# Keep active sidebar menu on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages, sidebar

I am using a sidebar menu from GitHub [here](https://github.com/huang-x-h/sidebar-menu)

I am implementing it in a .Net master page and trying to keep the expanded/selected menu item selected on postback and having no luck.

sidebar-menu.js file, handling the creation and click event, as listed in GitHub, is:

```
$.sidebarMenu = function (menu) {
    var animationSpeed = 300,
        subMenuSelector = '.sidebar-submenu';

    $(menu).on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var checkElement = $this.next();

        if (checkElement.is(subMenuSelector) && checkElement.is(':visible')) {
            checkElement.slideUp(animationSpeed, function () {
                checkElement.removeClass('menu-open');
            });
            checkElement.parent("li").removeClass("active");
        }

        //If the menu is not visible
        else if ((checkElement.is(subMenuSelector)) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            //Get the parent menu
            var parent = $this.parents('ul').first();
            //Close all open menus within the parent
            var ul = parent.find('ul:visible').slideUp(animationSpeed);
            //Remove the menu-open class from the parent
            ul.removeClass('menu-open');
            //Get the parent li
            var parent_li = $this.parent("li");

            //Open the target menu and add the menu-open class
            checkElement.slideDown(animationSpeed, function () {
                //Add the class active to the parent li
                checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
                parent.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
                parent_li.addClass('active');
            });
        }
        //if this isn't a link, prevent the page from being redirected
        if (checkElement.is(subMenuSelector)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

The HTML used to crate the menu:

```
<section style="width: 200px">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="sidebar-header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
                <li><a href="Dashboard.aspx" class="navLink"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../index2.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                <span>Layout Options</span>
                <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sidebar-submenu" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="Test1.aspx" class="navLink"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Top Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="boxed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Boxed</a></li>
                <li><a href="fixed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Fixed</a></li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Collapsed Sidebar</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</section>
```

and it is instantiated using:

```
<script src="sidebar-menu.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {debugger
        $.sidebarMenu($('.sidebar-menu'));
</script>
```

So, I tried to store the current item clicked in local storage and on page postback call the click method using the stored link so as to re-expand/select the the selected item.

```
<li><a href="Dashboard.aspx" class="navLink">  // I added the class to anchor


<script src="sidebar-menu.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {debugger
        $.sidebarMenu($('.sidebar-menu'));

        currMenu = localStorage.getItem('currentMenu');
        if (currMenu != null)
            $('.sidebar-menu').click(currMenu);
    });

    $(".navLink").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('currentMenu',currMenu); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, not sure perhaps have a field to toggle the visibility?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do I have to modify the original JS file creating the menu and handling its onclick event? I am not sure if my approach is correct, namely trying to store selected item and programmatically do a "click" on it. Even this I cannot get right!

Comment: When you change or select a page from the vertical menu, for example the "Charts" menu (the menu expands) and clic the "ChartJS" item, is the moment when you lose the master page view state and you want to keep "open" the visual effect on the "Chart" menu?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Right now, as soon as I click on ChartJS and a postback is performed to display the content, all menu items collapse.

Comment: The localStorage solution should work for this case when the page has finishes loading